# Need to create a tag for deploying sprint changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Need to create a tag for deploying sprint changes in to prod env in Azure devops??

I tried some approaches but couldn't figure it out.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you specify where you want to put the tag on or what you want to tag? repo, build, release?

Comment: Automatically a tag needs to get add to dev branch by end of each sprint.

Comment: `Tag Git Release` task probably is what you are looking for. You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

**Tag Git Release** task

You can use task `Tag Git Release` at the end of your deployment pipeline.

1, In additional options of the deployment job, Check `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`
[image]

2, Add `Tag Git Release` task

[image]

**Powershell task**

Powershell is an another way to achieve this. But it is a little complicated.
For it has to call restful API to set the tag to dev branch.

1,add a powershell task to the end of your deployment pipeline.

[image]

2,Call restful api to set the tag to specified branch. Tag branch is actually based on commit id.So in the requeset body `$(Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion)` to refer the commit ID.

To get your person assess token refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops).

For more information about release variable check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch).

```
$url ="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/{repo Name}/annotatedtags?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$bodyrb = "{'message': 'tag for develop via api', 'name': 'tagfromazuredpowershellapi', 'taggedObject': {'objectId':'$(Release.Artifacts.{alias}-CI.SourceVersion)'}}"

connectionToken="{person assess token}}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $bodyrb
```

Hope above could be of a litte help!